# What's the meaning of "みたい" in the following context?

Tags: grammar, meaning, syntax

To give a bit of context, this is a text found on a DS game where some options are shown on the lower screen. The full text is the following:

> したがめんを　タッチして　みたい　こうもくを　えらんで　ください

I understand that the general meaning of the text is "Please, choose one of the options below" or "Select your preferences below", but I have trouble understanding the function of "みたい" in there.

I looked up "みたい" and it seems to be used to express similarity or comparing things, but it does not seem to have that function in here.

To make a comparison with something I know, I was wondering if it is treated the same as "parezca" in Spanish as in "Elige la opción que te parezca mejor". "parecer" also expresses similarity but can be used to make the reader to choose.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This みたい is the [tai-form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/desire) (a.k.a. desire-form) of the verb 見る ("to see"). The sentence may be easier to read in kanji:

> **見たい**項目を選んでください。
> Please choose the item **[you] want to see**.

Note that a tai-form conjugates like an i-adjective, and thus it can directly modify the following noun. みたい meaning "to look like ～" has nothing to do with this sentence. (みたい for similarity conjugates as a na-adjective, so it cannot directly modify 項目.)